# Customizing Identify Dialog in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcmap

Any idea for customizing Identify Dialog in ArcMap.I want to use my control (for example a list view or a custom control) to show attributes of features in same native ArcMap Identify Dialog,mean replacing some controls of that dialog box.If ArcObject doesn't expose any interface for this purpose,is there any way to replace whole dialog with another dialog but still using same tool,I mean using ArcMap native identify tool,we can show a complete different dialog box which simulates same functionalities.

Any idea,help or guide line would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to edit the complete forms themselves that ESRI provides, you can only access them and use them.

A solution for your problem involves two parts:

1) A form that that accesses the functionality of the IIdentifyDialog interface and has the customization you desire. You could make it very similar to the ESRI form by plugging in various properties of IIdentifyDialog but then add your own tweaks such as the listbox you mentioned.

2) A custom identify tool that instantiates a new IIdentifyDialog, but **doesn't actually show the dialog**. Instead, it shows your form. The OnClick method of the tool opens your custom form and then calls the methods and properties of IIdentifyDialog **without actually showing the dialog** and then populates your custom form. Essentially, the form would remain hidden in the background and do all the identifying work for you, and you could just grab the values of it from your instantiation of IIdentifyDialog and populate your custom form as needed.

The custom identify tool is already mostly written for you.

Custom identify tool in VB:http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/samples/arcmap/identifydialog.htm
Custom identify tool in C#:http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1707&t=172833

Comment: The links are broken here.

Comment: Odd - they work fine from my end (in USA). Perhaps it is a UK issue?

Comment: Yep - they work for me now - and then once it didn't.  God knows!